# Angularjs: Dynamic Input in a single array for row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I'm a newbie and I need some help for something you'll maybe find too easy.

I want to add with a single button different inputs at the same time.
I don't know how to manage.
This is what I'm doing, and I'm blocked.
I'll thank you your ideas.

So, my form shows each name and an input box for entering the age of that person (We don't know how many persons are in 'people').
And in the end, an 'submit' button that calls the showAll() function.

And then, I just want to show the content of the array in console.log

A Form like this:
[Form with only 3 people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCDim.jpg)

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm3">
  <div class="form-group row" ng-repeat="person in people track by $index">
    <label for="player" class="col-xs-3 col-form-label text-right">{{ person.name }}</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control" type="text"  ng-model="person.age[$index]" required>
    </div>
  </div>                    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="showAll()" >Show all</button>
</form>
```

**controller.js:**

```
  $scope.person = [];
  // POST
    $scope.showAll = function() {
        for (var i=0; i < person.length; i++){ 
    console.log('person: ' + {{ $scope.person[i] }} );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the inputs by using `ng-if` or `ng-hide` and show them on `showAll` by setting that variable used by those to `true` or `false`:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" ng-if="person.show">
  <input class="form-control" type="text"  ng-model="person.age[$index]" required>
</div>
```

And in `showAll`:

```
$scope.showAll = function() {
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.people.length; i++) { 
        $scope.people[i].show = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: No, that's not what I was looking for.
console.log was just a way to know if I can get the data from the new array people, wich contains all names and ages saved with the same button.

i.e.: I'm unable to see what's in  people.age[1]. It seems that is not the right way to save all inputs at the same time.
If that would be with different fields, it would be easy. But with the same field (age)...  I can't do it!